# Embed swf as Preloader

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, flash, wordpress

I have a preloader file that has animated bars and percentage. all in all, an swf file ;)

is there any script that will let me use it on my Wordpress website as preloader? if so what is the code and where to embed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is it that you're trying to preload? You need a way to specify what the file(s) is/are that you're loading, either by modifying your preloader's AS3 code, or possibly through the use of an object key in your embed code.

Comment: im trying to load this file http://activeden.net/item/equalizer-style-preloader/45301

Comment: i cant post it here..(i think)

Comment: @user1562911 I'm pretty sure that preloader is intended to be imported into the Flash project for whatever your Flash/AS3 content is that you are preloading.

Comment: I see..is there a way to implement it in a jQuery container like this -> http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/queryloader2-preload-your-images-with-ease/

Comment: I think that you need to figure out what it is you are actually trying to do, go do some research on your own, and then come back to SO if you have more specific questions.

Comment: Im guessing there are some things i didn't fully researched..thanx for the help though.